# Open DLL in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, zxing, dllimport

I wanted to use ZXing library and to check some demos first. Website says:

> The following demo clients are available:
>   -Unity3D and Vuforia demo (demonstrates encoding of barcodes and decoding of images from a camera with Unity3D)

I downloaded it, and it just a bunch of DLL files:

[image]

How do I **run it in unity**? This is supposed to be some sort of sample or demo, because demos for other platforms, like windows, contain .EXE files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the whole demo project.
https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/UnityDemo/
I think that will make the use of the libraries much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not "run it" anywhere, as they are just libraries.
The purpose of a DLL is to hold code that you can reference, dlls are not executables

You can reference these libraries from within your project and then see the referrence on ZXing library ( just google for it and the Git will come up ) and you can then use methods,classes etc from within those dlls.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but found only java repository, I'm afraid